# Ping, HTTP Failure between Windows XP and Android

Tags: android, windows, networking

I have a web application running on my development machine which is a Windows XP machine. I'm trying to access the URL from my Android phone Chrome browser, but it is failing with a ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE . Both the devices are on the same WiFi having IPs `x.x.x.102` and `x.x.x.103`

I'm unable to ping both the IPs from each other.

Surprisingly, I have another Ubuntu server(`x.x.x.101`) on the same network on which I'm able to ping both the IPs and also access the web application running on the windows XP machine. Can anyone please let me know how do I go about debugging what seems to be a networking issue.
Cheers!

Comment: Switch off the firewall.

Comment: Oops.. forgot to mention, the Firewall is turned off, like I mentioned in the description, I'm able to ping as well as access the URL from a 3rd Linux machine which is also on the same network. If firewall was an issue, it should not have been accessible from there as well, nonetheless the firewall on the windows machine is turned off.